# How to insert missing data into a pandas dataframe, using another dataframe that has the missing info?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have a dataframe of leads as such:

```
import pandas as pd

leads = {'Unique Identifier':['1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8'],
        'Name': ['brad','stacy','holly','mike','phil', 'chris','jane','glenn'],
        'Channel': [None,None,None,None,'facebook', 'facebook','google', 'facebook'],
        'Campaign': [None,None,None,None,'A', 'B','B', 'C'],
        'Gender': ['M','F','F','M','M', 'M','F','M'],
        'Signup Month':['Mar','Mar','Apr','May','May','May','Jun','Jun']
        }

leads_df = pd.DataFrame(leads)

leads_df
```

which looks like the following. It has missing data for Channel and Campaign for the first 4 leads.

[leads table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zluPA.png)

I have a separate dataframe with the missing data:

```
missing = {'Unique Identifier':['1','2','3','4'],
        'Channel': ['google', 'email','facebook', 'google'],
        'Campaign': ['B', 'A','C', 'B']
        }

missing_df = pd.DataFrame(missing)

missing_df
```

[table with missing data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tOZed.png)

Using the Unique Identifiers in both tables, how would I go about plugging in the missing data into the main leads table? For context there are about 6,000 leads with missing data.

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the two dataframes together, update the columns using the results from the merge and then proceed to drop the merged columns.

```
data = leads_df.merge(missing_df, how='outer', on='Unique Identifier')
data['Channel'] = data['Channel_y'].fillna(data['Channel_x'])
data['Campaign'] = data['Campaign_y'].fillna(data['Campaign_x'])
data.drop(['Channel_x', 'Channel_y', 'Campaign_x', 'Campaign_y'], 1, inplace=True)
```

The result:

```
data
  Unique Identifier   Name Gender Signup Month   Channel Campaign
0                 1   brad      M          Mar    google        B
1                 2  stacy      F          Mar     email        A
2                 3  holly      F          Apr  facebook        C
3                 4   mike      M          May    google        B
4                 5   phil      M          May  facebook        A
5                 6  chris      M          May  facebook        B
6                 7   jane      F          Jun    google        B
7                 8  glenn      M          Jun  facebook        C
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the index of both dataframes to `unique identifier` and use `combine_first` to fill the null values in `leads_df`

```
(leads_df
.set_index("Unique Identifier")
.combine_first(missing_df.set_index("Unique Identifier"))
.reset_index()
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I use in this kind of case is similar to vlookup function of Excel.

```
leads_df.loc[leads_df.Channel.isna(),'Channel']=pd.merge(leads_df.loc[leads_df.Channel.isna(),'Unique Identifier'],                                             
                                                         missing_df,
                                                         how='left')['Channel']
```

This code will result in :

```
  Unique Identifier   Name   Channel Campaign Gender Signup Month
0                 1   brad    google     None      M          Mar
1                 2  stacy     email     None      F          Mar
2                 3  holly  facebook     None      F          Apr
3                 4   mike    google     None      M          May
4                 5   phil  facebook        A      M          May
5                 6  chris  facebook        B      M          May
6                 7   jane    google        B      F          Jun
7                 8  glenn  facebook        C      M          Jun
```

You can do same to 'Campaign'.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to fill it using fillna() ...

```
leads_df.fillna(missing_df, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a pandas DataFrame method for this called [combine_first](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
voltron = leads_df.combine_first(missing_df)
```